# Does Wunderlist store data in the server in encrypted form?

Tags: applications, security, privacy

How secure and private is Wunderlist? For example does it only transfer data in encrypted form but stores it unencrypted? I would like to be able to store passwords relating to work on my phone but am not sure this is safe enough.

Comment: Do you have any references to such claim? This question would probably be answerable only by Wunderlist's developers themselves, unless someone do experiments on this. (Still, there's no way to know if it's stored encrypted or not).

Comment: "Data are transmitted to the respective terminal using SSL encryption so that your data are transmitted securely" from https://www.wunderlist.com/privacy-policy/ but doesn't say how safe data is on servers

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm thinking of how lastpass only stores encrypted data on the server and only once it's on your device and you enter the master password is it decrypted, so no one else (even the owners of the servers) can get to it.

Comment: Point taken, but LastPass is made specially to handle passwords, thus security is the most important feature. Wunderlist, on the other hand, seems to be a general task/to-do lists. Securing data seems not their first focus. Anyway, why don't you try to contact their developers first, since I think it's easier to do that at the moment?

Answer (score -1):

Wunderlist is safe for all kind of data storage.

- Data is encrypted in transit by 256-bit SSL encryption.
- Passwords are encrypted through the same protocol in transit and at rest.
- Data put into Wunderlist is stored specifically on 6 Wunderkinder servers, operated by Amazon Web Services in Ireland.
- As such, 6 Wunderkinder abides by EU and German data/privacy protection requirements, traditionally stricter than US requirements.
- Those maintaining the servers operated by Amazon Web Services are trained and screened to the utmost standard. Their site on compliance: http://aws.amazon.com/compliance/
- Lastly, 6Wunderkinder’s practices passed through a 3rd party audit, performed by Stratum Security in 2013.
  If you have any more questions, especially regarding industry-specific compliance, please reach out to use via business@wunderlist.com

Comment: This answer does not say anything about encryption at rest or who has access to keys.

Comment: Where did you get this information?